# EF Core string contains string array

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Is it possible to check with EF Core if a string contains a string[]

For example, I have a database table that has comma separated keywords in one columns. I want to get related records that also contain these keywords. The way I tried it:

```
public class Item {

  int Id { get; set; }

  string Keywords { get; set; }

}
```

```
var keywords = item.Keywords.Split(',');

var result = context.Items.Where(i => keywords.Any(j => i.Keywords.Contains(j)).ToListAsync();
```

This will throw a error message:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(g => __keywords_0.Any(j =>
> g.Keywords.Contains(j)))' could not be translated.

So how wil I rewrite this so that it can be translated to SQL? It is not an option to get a complete list and checking it with C#. It is also not possible to convert a comma seperated keyword list to it's own table.

Comment: Did you try this `context.Items.Where(i => keywords.contains(i.Keywords).ToListAsync();` @Roy Berris

Comment: @Eldho woudn't work because for example, "car,building,pool" (`keywords`) doesn't contain "apple,car,bike" (`i.Keywords`)

Comment: your keywords converting to string array[] so we are comparing each item against `i.keywords` so which is contains. Car keyword contains in apple,car,bike (i.keywords) so shouldn't it work ?

Comment: @Eldho also no because `[ "car", "building", "pool"]` (`keywords`) doesnt' contain "apple,car,bike" (`i.Keywords`). It needs to match whole strings. Your logic would work the other way around, which I wrote in the original post but that can't be translated to SQL.

Comment: Do you want it to convert it to `LIKE '%car,building,pool%'`? What if the record has it but in different order: 'pool,car,building'?

Comment: Create your own custom expression tree.  which just checks each value, OR you can just make multiple requests to the database using a foreach

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to generate a dynamic expression, an example can be found in this issue on EF Core Github repository:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10834#issuecomment-362221156

It would be great if something like this can be eventually added to the EF Core/Linq to SQL directly, I find it very useful.

Implementation from the comment:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return queryable.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        predicates.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, bool>>, Expression>(
            null,
            (current, predicate) =>
            {
                var visitor = new ParameterSubstitutionVisitor(predicate.Parameters[0], parameter);
                return current != null ? Expression.OrElse(current, visitor.Visit(predicate.Body)) : visitor.Visit(predicate.Body);
           }),
        parameter));
}

private class ParameterSubstitutionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _destination;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _source;

    public ParameterSubstitutionVisitor(ParameterExpression source, ParameterExpression destination)
    {
        _source = source;
        _destination = destination;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(node, _source) ? _destination : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var predicate = keywords.Select(k => (Expression<Func<Item, bool>>)(i => EF.Functions.Like(i.Keywords, k)));
context.Items.WhereAny(predicate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use something like this

```
public class Product
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public List<StringList> Strings{ get; set; }

}

public class StringList
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

`List<StringList>` will replace `List<String>`
For Example `DB.Products.Include(x => x.Strings).ToList().ForEach(y => Console.WriteLine(y.Name));`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I can't migrate database in any way like I described in the post. So this won't work for me unfortunately.